# How can I use GDB on Ubuntu without installation?

Tags: ubuntu, gdb

How can I use GDB on Ubuntu without installation?

I tried moving gdb installation files to a temporary directory, but I don't have any auth from that server.

Is there any portable version of gdb for Linux?

I tried to configure include prefix option and `make install` in `/tmp/my_own_directory`.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do I need to do?

Step 0: learn to ask better questions. In particular, saying "I tried this" *without* explaining what problem you've run into does *not* make a good question.

> Is there any portable version of gdb for Linux?

All versions of GDB are.

> I tried moving gdb installation files to a temporary directory, but I don't have any auth from that server.

*Surely* you don't need any "auth" to move files to a temporary directory.

Now, what you *probably* did was get a package suitable for your distribution, and tried to install it via the appropriate package manager, but *that* does require administrative privileges.

There are two ways to deal with that:

1. Instead of *installing* the package, *unpack* it. For a debian package, `dpkg -x foo.deb foo` would do that. For an RPM, `rpm2cpio foo.rpm | cpio -idmv` would do.
2. Alternatively, building GDB from source is not hard:

   `mkdir gdb && cd gdb &&
    tar xvzf gdb-x.y.tar.gz &&
    mkdir build && cd build &&
    ../configure --prefix $HOME/gdb && make && make install`

Comment: I tried before that your solution. but I didn't have administrative privileges. so I failed to install. I just wanted to install without administrative privileges. Anyway thank you for your answer.